# ReadFeeds vs Query vs Read in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I would like to verify if my understanding is correct about OperationType in Cosmos DB (Cassandra API), as I cannot find a good explanation in the documentation.

Basically I have run a few different cases on Cosmos DB, and I see that when I query data using partition key, then only ReadFeed is used. But when I am not using partition key, then OperationType "Query" is used. It means that apparently in the first case it doesn't use the query engine and goes directly to the storage and in the second case Query Engine is used. Does it sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read** is when you [Get a Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document)

> The Get Document operation retrieves a document by its partition key and document key.

**ReadFeed** is when you [List Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-documents)

> Performing a GET on the documents resource of a particular collection, i.e. the docs URI path, returns a list of documents under the collection. ReadFeed can be used to retrieve all documents, or just the incremental changes to documents within the collection.

**Query** is when you [Query Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents) (Search)

> You can query arbitrary json documents in a collection by performing a post against the “colls” resource in Cosmos DB.

ReadFeed or change feed is an internal feature of Cosmos DB. Other DBs maintain a feed of changes as well. They may expose it and you can interact with it in the ways they make available. They will use the feed of changes internally for many things. Cosmos DB are probably able to satisfy your query when you filter by partition using the ReedFeed.