# Azure Cosmos db monitoring metrics

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-monitoring

Below is the total requests metric of various 'operationtype' against a particular cosmosdb collection.

1. What does particularly "Execute" and "Readfeed" operation type mean?
2. Below metrics does not cover the operations performed via stored procs as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor?tabs=azure-diagnostics#:%7E:text=The%20operations%20executed%20via%20Stored%20procedure%20aren%27t%20logged%20so%20they%20aren%27t%20available%20under%20the%20OperationType%20metric.), so how to get total read/write operation metrics performed via stored procs?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Execute** operation type refers to the Execution of Stored Procedures.

**Readfeed** operation is  to retrieve all documents, or just the incremental changes to documents within the collection.

As mentioned in the documentation, currently metrics does not capture the operations performed via the SP. You might need to log it somewhere manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
  What does particularly "Execute" and "Readfeed" operation type mean?
```

Refer this [ReadFeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-documents) Microsoft documentation.

- **Read Feed can be used to retrieve all documents i.e., refers to read the entire feed of a container**

  ```
  Execute  operation type.
  ```
- **It executes   user-defined functions or JavaScript stored procedures.**
  [image]
  [image]

You can also Refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71856871/readfeeds-vs-query-vs-read-in-cosmosdb) for Read vs Read Feeds Vs Query.

AFAIK you can capture metrics using [application insights](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/capture-metrics-for-cosmos-db-using-application-insights) or you can use context object provided by cosmos DB and in your stored procedures, use the SDK to track custom events and metrics.